# Adjust all div's equally with the condition that one div may have upto 8 nested div and other has only one

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

This is basic html with bootstrap flexbox. The second div may contain it's nested div upto 8. And the result should be like attached screenshots.
Can it be done with given structure. Am attaching most of the scenario's along with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Chat Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .chat{

  }
  .chat .chat-part{
      height: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Grid Structure</h1>
  <p>Condition is one div always one or more than div inside it.</p>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row chat">
      <!-- This is first div -->
      <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">owner</div>
      <!-- This is second div -->
      <div class="col d-flex px-0 chat-part">
       <!-- This div may have upto 8 nested div's -->
            <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">chat1</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">chat2</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">chat3</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">chat4</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You can achieve this by using flexbox.
Use `.flex-column` to set a vertical direction

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Chat Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .chat{

  }
  .chat .chat-part{
      min-height: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Grid Structure</h1>
  <p>Condition is one div always one or more than div inside it.</p>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row  chat flex-column">
      <!-- This is first div -->
      <div class="col chat-part" style="background-color:red;">Owner</div>

      <!-- This is second div -->
      <div class="col d-flex px-0 chat-part">
       <!-- This div may have upto 8 nested div's -->
            <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">chat1</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">chat2</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">chat3</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">chat4</div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what about when we have 3 chats only?
When we have 3 chats and one owner, then it should be look like first screenshot.